# Creating and exit from text file by using Shell Script

Tags: shell

I write a shell script to input Folder Name & Port Number 2 parameters asking one by one but when i execute that shell script it will ask both values in single first i want to ask this one by one by giving input, second when i enter both value or pass parameter then text file is generate and values save.

But when i enter both values and enter "I WANT MY REGULAR PROMPT AS USUAL" BELOW IS EXAMPLE

```
echo "Enter FolderName : "
echo "Enter PortNumber : "
cat >> myfile.txt
sudo chmod +x myfile.txt
```

After giving input for both values file created and prompt as usual promp.

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$

PLEASE HELP

Comment: check https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html

Comment: echo "Enter Name : "
echo "Enter City : "
cat >> myfile.txt   << EOF   - IF IF WRITE THIS HERE WITHOUT TAKING INPUTS GETTING PROMPT 

AND IF ENTER AND WRITE << EOF THEN NEED TO PRESS ^C FOR SAVING THIS….